# Reference js file using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, elm

I am new to webpack, and am using it to compile my Elm project.

I have the following configuration file

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      './src/index.js'
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ]
      },
      {
        test:    /\.html$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader:  'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test:    /\.elm$/,
        exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
        loader:  'elm-webpack-loader?verbose=true&warn=true',
          options: {debug: true, warn: true},
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      }
    ],

    noParse: /\.elm$/,
  },

  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    stats: { colors: true },
  },


};
```

I am trying to reference dexie.js in my index file (before that everything compiled). It is located in "node_modules\dexie\dist\dexie.js"

```
'use strict';

require('ace-css/css/ace.css');
require('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');
//
// Require index.html so it gets copied to dist
require('./index.html');
require('./dexie/dist/dexie.js');

...
```

> 9:54:44 PM client.1 |  Started compiling Elm.. 9:54:45 PM client.1 | 
>   Hash: c738c54879238b5512ca 9:54:45 PM client.1 |  Version: webpack
>   3.9.1 9:54:45 PM client.1 |  Time: 1693ms 9:54:45 PM client.1 |       Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names 9:54:45 PM
>   client.1 |  index.html  199 bytes 9:54:45 PM client.1 |      app.js
>   1.19 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  app 9:54:45 PM client.1 |     [4] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./src/index.js
>   40 bytes {0} 9:54:45 PM client.1 |     [5]
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 7.95 kB {0} 9:54:45
>   PM client.1 |     [6] ./node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} 9:54:45 PM
>   client.1 |     [9] ./node_modules/url/util.js 314 bytes {0} 9:54:45 PM
>   client.1 |    [13] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0}
>   9:54:45 PM client.1 |    [14] ./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js 135
>   bytes {0} 9:54:45 PM client.1 |    [15]
>   ./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.86 kB {0} 9:54:45 PM
>   client.1 |    [16] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 kB {0}
>   9:54:45 PM client.1 |    [18] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js
>   3.73 kB {0} 9:54:45 PM client.1 |    [23] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^./log$ 170 bytes {0} [built] 9:54:45 PM client.1 |    [25]
>   (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} 9:54:45 PM client.1 |    [27]
>   ./src/index.js 1.32 kB {0} [built] 9:54:45 PM client.1 |    [28]
>   ./node_modules/ace-css/css/ace.css 964 bytes {0} 9:54:45 PM client.1 |
>   [39] ./src/index.html 56 bytes {0} 9:54:45 PM client.1 |    [40]
>   ./src/Main.elm 814 kB {0} [built] 9:54:45 PM client.1 |      + 18
>   hidden modules 9:54:45 PM client.1 |  ERROR in ./src/index.js 9:54:45
>   PM client.1 |  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './dexie/dist/dixie.js' in 'C:\Pvt\positron\Elm.Mobile\src

I took a shot in the dark and added:

```
{
        test:    /\.js$/,
        loader:  'file-loader',
},
```

but it did not work either.

Comment: What if you put `require('dexie/dist/dixie.js');` or `require('dixie')` instead of `require('./dexie/dist/dixie.js');`?

Comment: Also fails with Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dexie/dist/dixie.js' in 'C:\Pvt\positron\Elm.Mobile\src'
10:04:53 PM client.1 |   @ ./src/index.js 9:0-30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I compare to what I use - https://github.com/simonh1000/elm-webpack-starter/blob/master/webpack.config.js - then what seems to be missing is a resolve section

```
resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, "src"),
            "node_modules"
        ],
        extensions: ['.js', '.elm', '.scss', '.png']
    },
```

Comment: I added your code and changed my code to say 
require('dexie'); and it worked then thanx